# Excel VSTO Add-In throwing null reference exceptions after installation on a standard user's machine

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop

I don't have much experience interfacing with Microsoft office products, and I've come to a dead end searching and trying resolve this issue. I've been actively creating a excel VSTO add-in as administrator on my machine being able to debug and run everything normally.

However, once I publish the application using ClickOnce and install the add-in using a standard user I receive the follow: **Custom UI Runtime Error in ... An exception occurred while calling function ... The exception message is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Also, catching the calls throws System.NullReferencesException errors on numerous associated functions.

I've tried quite a few solutions that I came across with no luck, and a lot leading me to solutions unrelated with excel. I've tried, signing certificates, interop annotations, publishing with ClickOnce, etc.

I'm using Visual Studios 2017 and the latest Microsoft Office 365, also, third party libraries, such as, Microsoft Extensions Dependency Injection, Entity Framework, etc., all in all, it seems to be failing when I try to show a custom windows form which implements the model-view-presenter design pattern.

In conclusion, I need to be able to run this add-in on standard user machines, and I'm getting close to the conclusion that this might not be possible without administrator privileges.

Comment: So what is returning null, and why, i mean we cant see your code to figure that out

Comment: Without seeing the code and knowing which command is triggering the error it's impossible for anyone to know. If you can't debug on the machine then use error logging to figure out where the problem is. Right off-hand, make sure all the necessary libraries are installed on the target machine or distributed with the application.